# Filtering QSqlRelation in QSqlRelationalTableModel

Tags: c++, sql, qt

I have two tables like:
Person (Id, Name, JobID, Age)
Jobs (Id, Company, Salary)

I'm using a SqlRelationalTableModel and it's working with the following QSqlRelation:

```
   model-> setTable("Person")
   model-> setRelation(2,QSqlRelation("Jobs", "Id", "Company"))
```

My problem is that now I want to show only the jobs with salaries over 50000 and I don't know how to filter Jobs table to do it since setFilter only affects Person table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QSqlQueryModel`

```
QSqlQueryModel* model = new QSqlQueryModel();
model->setQuery("select * from Person left join Jobs on Person.JobID=Jobs.Id where Salary>50000");
```

Comment: What if I still need to support updates on the table?