# Filter options provided by QSqlRelationalDelegate/QSqlRelation acourding to some WHERE close

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qsqltablemodel, qsqlrelationaltablemodel

I have a `QTableView` populated by `QSqlRelationalTableModel`.

There is a column that references another table, so when I edit/create a row, this column's editor is `QCombobox` which gets its data from the related table. The problem is that I want to filter the data with some predefined *WHERE* close on the related table.

Example:

**Tables**:

```
Person:
id, name, job_id;

Job:
id, title, salary
```

What I want is something like

```
model.setRelation(3,QSqlRelation("Job", "id", "title", "WHERE salary > 50000"))
```

So that the QCombobox will have only Job titles with salaries > 5000.

I cannot use `QSqlQueryModel` as suggested in [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65291796/filtering-qsqlrelation-in-qsqlrelationaltablemodel) - I still need users to be able to add new data or edit existing data.

It seems that [someone managed to achieve this 10 years ago](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/48800-Filter-relation-column-options-QSqlRelationalDelegate-constrain-or-restrict-option) by tweaking the QT source code, but my C++ is bad so I could not figure it out quite well.

**Possible solutions:**

1. The first thing that comes to mind is to implement my own `QSqlRelationalDelagate` and populate `QCombobox` in the `createEditor` and set appropriate values in `setModelData`. I will try to do it myself and report the results back here. But it seems not very *clean* to me.
2. The best way would be to *Extend* the functionality of the `QSqlRelation` or `QSqlRelationalTableModel` but the documentation on it seems to be not very clear. So the real question is for experienced QT/PyQT developers: **How do I solve the problem this way?**

---

**Update**

So filtering out the contents of the `QCombobox` in the `createEditor` of the delegate works, but it requires a database query every time the editor is created which seems a bit off. And also it was quite a mess to handle new indexes after filtering. But I still wonder about the second way of approaching the problem.